# SQL Task in SSIS foreach loop -- Max pool size was reached error

Tags: sql, ssis, connection-pooling, pooling

I am using a foreach loop in SSIS to iterate over the contents of a folder, executing a SQL Task for each file.

When I do this, it works fine the first ~300 times through the loop, then it hangs and says:

```
Error: 0xC002F210 at ______, Execute SQL Task: Executing the query "[__].[dbo].[_______]" 
failed with the following error: "Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to 
obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections 
were in use and max pool size was reached.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the 
query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not
established correctly.
```

I'd imagine that this means that the old tasks are closing too slowly?  The real kicker is that if I then add another SQL Task (inserting a blank string into a tmp table, using the same connection) *before* the task that is failing, the whole thing will work just fine.  This isn't a good solution though, and I am hoping to figure out if there is a known workaround or if I am doing something very foolish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an option in the connection manager to reuse the existing connection.  Maybe changing this setting will help.

Select properties for your connection manager and set the RetainSameConnection property to True.

Comment: Dang! I thought that this was going to work for sure! Hadn't seen that property.  Somehow, I'm now getting 15 more items processed, but it still crashes!

Comment: I take that back--I was using an XML config file and had to change the retainSameConnection property in that too; now it works! Thanks!